date discrepancies in logs
I have a situation, i reinstalled Ubuntu from a flash drive this morning(July 27).  Now when investigating changes to the system I am finding logs from July 24.  How is this possible?

You've provided few specifics so we cannot do much. Ubuntu has many products/releases that use different installers and we don't know which you used as you gave no specifics. If your machine doesn't have internet available it'll use date/times set locally which maybe incorrect, let alone timezone differences.. and some logs using UTC times (not local time). We can only guess as to what you're referring to, as you've provided no specifics.

I would guess that because you reinstalled Ubuntu, it would be either:

It's pulling from your previous install, or
It's showing logs from before it connected to the Internet and time-synced with NTP.

